# openssl error ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Tags: macos, go, openssl, homebrew, tdlib

There's an error while compilating tdlib program related to the openssl call.

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running cc failed: exit status 1
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The openssl was already installed with brew:

```
which openssl
/opt/homebrew/bin/openssl
```

```
==> openssl@3: stable 3.1.2 (bottled)
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2 (6,495 files, 28.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-09-21 at 14:06:03
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/o/openssl@3.rb
License: Apache-2.0
```

I'm tried to use pkg-config and exporing next envs to solve this issue, but nothing helps.

```
export CGO_CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags openssl)
export CGO_LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs openssl)
```

Comment: Could you run `find / -iname "*libssl*"` ? the error is for libssl.so, openssl is a binary.

Comment: @HarishGanesan

/opt/homebrew/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/opt/homebrew/lib/libssl.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libssl.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libssl.a
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/lib/libssl.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/lib/libssl.3.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/lib/libssl.a

Comment: For pkg-config to work properly, first the PKG_CONFIG_PATH has to have the path of the .pc file corresponding to the library. In your case, you should check if /opt/homebrew/pkgconfig is part of that list.

Comment: tdlib has some detailed instructions for building on macos here: https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/ios/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u chech with these flags too (.~/bashrc or ~/.zshrc):

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
```

or u can use pkg-config:

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags openssl)"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --libs openssl)"
```